# Donut chart is not updating with new values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a donut chart that's rendered based on the values of objects in an array. The initial render works just fine, but I can't seem to get the update to work -- I change the data but it doesn't update visually. I followed this example: http://jsfiddle.net/N5Znf/

And here's my current code: http://jsbin.com/eGaziZA/1/edit

The relevant update part in my code:

```
$scope.dataset = [
    metric: 'advocacy',
    amount: 1
  },
  {
    metric: 'appreciation',
    amount: 8
  },
  {
    metric: 'awareness',
    amount: 1
  }
];

arcs = arcs.data(pie($scope.dataset));
arcs.transition().duration(500);
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reapply the update join

```
    .attr({
            d: arc,
            'class': function (d) {
              return d.data.metric;
            }
          })
```

after providing new data : http://jsbin.com/eGaziZA/3/edit

I would probably abstract out the render method from the initialrender and the update functions so that you aren't repeating code. The transition doesn't look very good in this example, but I haven't work with d3's pie layout so I don't know how to make them look better.

Answer (score 0):

You're really only missing the part where you update the arcs based on the new data. That is, the last line in your update function should be

arcs.transition().duration(500).attr("d", arc);

This won't work entirely as expected because you can't really interpolate curves linearly. So add a custom tween function like so

```
function arcTween(a) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}
```

and use that instead (not forgetting to initialise the `._current` member). Complete example [here](http://jsbin.com/enOkuyo/1/edit).